# Is there a command to alternate buffers?

Tags: buffers

I want to quickly alternate between the buffer I'm in and the last buffer I was in. Is there a built-in command for this?

I rolled my own, but I might rather use something built-in.

```
(defun alternate-buffer ()
  "Alternate between the current buffer and the previous."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (caar (window-prev-buffers))))
```

I've checked `M-x apropos` and searched for "buffer", but I haven't located such a command.

Comment: `C-x b Enter` not the same ?

Comment: Sure, but that's one extra keystroke. I want to go to the alternate buffer directly.

Comment: To note, an argument of `nil` to `switch-to-buffer` switches to the previous buffer that you selected in the current frame. This is slightly different as your function seems to only consider the current window history. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Interesting, that is slightly different when multiple windows are open, and I think I prefer the behavior of `alternate-buffer` in that case, as it feels more "predictable" for the way that I use windows.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function

```
(defun switch-to-previous-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))
```

Still custom elisp, but better that `caar`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with the modern completion systems:
[Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) or
[Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper).  Use `helm-buffers-list` or
`ivy-switch-buffer` correspondingly.

Now here's the trick: repeatedly press <kbd>C-M-n</kbd> to switch to
the next buffer without exiting the completion. Press <kbd>C-M-p</kbd>
for the previous buffer.  Finally, press <kbd>C-m</kbd> to exit
completion.

Answer (score 0):

How about?:

`previous-buffer` ["*In selected window switch to previous buffer.*"]

and

`next-buffer` ["*In selected window switch to next buffer.*"]

Both are built-in functions defined in `window.el` and come with their own keyboard shortcuts, which you can of course change or create additional ones.

Comment: I just saw that the other thread cited as a duplicate also included this solution, so I am respectfully voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The command you're looking for is `switch-to-other-buffer`. I bind it to F9, and use it frequently.

Update: My bad - it's an elisp function co-opted from Xemacs:

```
;; Switch To Other Buffer, from Xemacs/files.el
(defun switch-to-other-buffer (arg)
 "Switch to the previous buffer.  With a numeric arg, n, switch to the nth
most recent buffer.  With an arg of 0, buries the current buffer at the
bottom of the buffer stack."
 (interactive "p")
 (if (eq arg 0)
 (bury-buffer (current-buffer)))
 (switch-to-buffer
  (if (<= arg 1) (other-buffer (current-buffer))
(nth (1+ arg) (buffer-list)))))
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this when I use `M-x`. Emacs version is GNU Emacs 24.5.

Comment: There is no such command in vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`). You will need to specify the library that defines it etc.